# Harddrive not visible after update

Tags: boot, 13.10, partitioning, system-installation, 14.04

Yesterday I upgraded from 13.04 to 14.
During the installation, I left - when I came back (a couple of hours later), it showed a black screen, nothing else. Nothing happened for about an hour, so I restarted.

Now, when I try to boot my computer, it gives an error: `No bootable device`

I can run Ubuntu from a LiveCD, but I can't reinstall Ubuntu. It doesn't find my original hard drive, just the usb drive.

Similarly, if I **Try Ubuntu** from the USB-stick and run gparted, it only recognizes the USB, but the hard drive is not visible.

Anyone have any ideas how to get Ubuntu to recognize my hard drive again?

Comment: Sounds like the hard drive has a problem. You can see if its visible in BIOS. If not, the drive is probably dead.

Comment: Use a Windows bootable DVD and see if you get the same errors. And enter BIOS setup and see if you have your boot priorities as they should be or just reset BIOS to its default settings and see what next.

Comment: There was a bug that caused some issues with grub, but I don't have the details as I performed a clean install rather than OTA upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

1. Your Hard Drive is not plugged in all the way - Very likely
2. Your Hard Drive is not enabled in BIOS - Likely
3. Your Hard Drive has no partition table - Likely
4. Your Hard Drive is broken - Likely
5. Your Hard Drive connector and/or socket is broken - Not Likely

---

Fixing #1:

1. Plug in your hard drive all the way

Fixing #2:

1. Go muck around in BIOS until you enable your hard drive

Fixing #3:

1. Boot to LiveCD
2. Run command in console: `ls /dev/ | grep sd`
3. If there's a result, continue. If no result, #4 or #5.
4. Use gParted to make new partition sector

Fixing #4:

1. Plug Hard Drive into other PC and see if it works.
2. If yes, #5. If no, HDD is broken (or #3).

Fixing #5:

1. Your hardware broke, bud. No way to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The drive isn't even visible in the BIOS, so its probably misconnected/dead. 
Weird, that this would happen during an OS update...

Will try to install a different HDD over the weekend.